# NFC Empty tag reading issue

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I am currently involved in a project in which I need to communicate using NFC.

When I'm trying to read an NFC tag, its perfectly working for URI and texts.

But when I'm trying to read an empty NFC tag its showing a default "Empty tag" message which is not defined in my code.

*AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<activity
  android:name=".ReadActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/example.nfcdemo"/>   
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>  
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

`onCreate()` method:

```
if (intent.getType() != null && intent.getType().equals(MimeType.NFC_DEMO)) {
  Parcelable[] rawMsgs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
  NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
  NdefRecord cardRecord = msg.getRecords()[0];
  String msg = new String(cardRecord.getPayload());
  displayMessage("Tag Written here : " +msg);
}
else {
  displayMessage("This is an empty tag");
}
```

I would like to show a custom message like this using my own activity.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to enable foreground dispatching. That way your activity can receive all NFC intents, including ones from empty tags. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch for instructions and example.

Comment: I have tried foreground dispatching also. it is not reading the tag when its empty. if tag contains some URLs or text, it is reading perfectly.I am using Ultralight C tags for this purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by "reading the tag"? If the tag is empty (meaning that there is no NDEF message), then Android will not send you an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent.

Comment: I want to check whether the Tag is empty or not before write the text/URI into the tag..If the tag is empty , i want to print a "Tag is Empty" message.. Any suggestions?